# Access object from outer select clause in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have the following LINQ Statement. I would like to find a way to use "r.Portfolio" while I am in the 3rd select clause (see comment in the code):

```
positionsToOptimize
    .Select(p => p)
    .SelectMany(r => r.Positions)
    .Select(pos => new OptimizedPosition() {
        CalculationType = TCalculationType.Absolute,
        Position = pos.NetPositionAmount,
        SecurityID = pos.SecurityID,
        Portfolio = r.Portfolio        // <- How do I do this? (Portfolio is not in 'pos')
    });
```

Essentially I am trying to replace the following foreach nested loop:

```
var lst = new List<OptimizedPosition>();
foreach (var r in positionsToOptimize) {
    foreach (var pos in r.Positions) {
        lst.Add(new OptimizedPosition() {
            CalculationType = TCalculationType.Absolute,
            Position = pos.NetPositionAmount,
            SecurityID = pos.SecurityID,
            SystemCode = r.SystemCode
        });
    }
}

return lst;
```

Comment: Why are you using three projections in the first place?  Just use a single projection and be done with it, rather than turning each object into something else just to turn that into *another* something else, just so you can turn it into *yet another* something else.

Comment: @Servy - I was trying to solve the problem using divide-and-conquer so tried to do multiple projections. Sometimes I guess that doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `SelectMany` select the final objects. `r` is already in scope in that lambda, no need to get clever. And you don't need to select `p => p`; `p` was already `p`.

```
var results =
    positionsToOptimize
    .SelectMany(r =>
        r.Positions.Select(pos => new OptimizedPosition()
        {
            CalculationType = TCalculationType.Absolute,
            Position = pos.NetPositionAmount,
            SecurityID = pos.SecurityID,
            Portfolio = r.Portfolio
        }
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

For cases when you need to use `SelectMany` and `Select` in the same query I would suggest to use linq syntax:

```
from r in positionsToOptimize
from pos in r.Positions
select new OptimizedPosition
{
    CalculationType = TCalculationType.Absolute,
    Position = pos.NetPositionAmount,
    SecurityID = pos.SecurityID,
    Portfolio = r.Portfolio
};
```

As you can see it is very clean and easy to read and doesn't require any additional temporary objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can select an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). Something like this:

```
positionsToOptimize
.Select(p => p)
.SelectMany(r => r.Positions.Select(c => new { temp = r, Positions = c }))
.Select(pos => new OptimizedPosition() 
{
    CalculationType = TCalculationType.Absolute,
    Position = pos.Positions.NetPositionAmount,
    SecurityID = pos.Positions.SecurityID,
    Portfolio = temp.Portfolio       
});
```

Comment: Interesting way to do it! I'll keep this in mind also!